# Is it formal to use "Usually" in the begining of the sentence

Tags: word-usage, style, formal-language

For example

> They are characterized by the amount of automation or the flexibility they provide. **Usually**, the more automation a method provides the less flexible it becomes.

Comment: looks totally fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely fine. That is to say, it's not overly-formal or informal - it's quite neutral in that sense. Fine for use in everyday speech, and fine to publish in a written academic document (for example). You could also consider the following alternatives (not an exhaustive list):

Typically

Often

As a rule

More often than not